# Accessing from 2nd row of the matrix in octave?

Tags: octave

I am new to octave and learning it.

Suppose I have a matrix X =
1 2
3 4
5 6

I want to access this matrix from second row, omitting the first row.
What is the syntax for it!?

I could delete the row by X(1,:) = [] which will change the original matrix,
How to access from the second row in octave?

Comment: I don' think I understand your question, could you provide expected output?

Comment: Expected output is 3,4; 5,6 , I donot want output, I want to multiply the matrix p * q where q dimension is from (row+1,col). For accessing from (row+1,col) do i need to delete the first row and save it in another variable or can I just multipy by accessing from second row!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use colon syntax. To return row 2 to the end use:

```
X(2:end, :)
```

See [GNU Octave documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html#Index-Expressions) for more indexing options.